# How to get a semilog curve to fit properly to the data?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some data on a semilog plot on y  axis. My Python Code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,13,14,15,16]
y1 = [18,12,9,7,1,6,1,2,1,1,1,1,1]
y = y1
x = x1

def s_plot(x,m,c):
    return np.power(10,(x*m+c))
pars, cov = curve_fit(f=s_plot,xdata=x, ydata=y, p0=[1,1 ])
```

On plotting the data and fitted curve I get a straight line instead of a semilog plot as shown below.

How can I get proper semilog curve fitting?

[image: current output with straight line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting `curve_fit` is mathematically correct. There is nothing wrong with your code either. Look at both images down there:
[image]

If you compare above plot to this one:
[image]

For the fit: the larger the x-value, the closer it is to zero (asymptote zero)
For the actual data: it stays constant at 1.

While the plot fit looks perfectly correct with a normal scaling (since the difference is **small** anyway), this will not be the case for the logarithmic scaling (which is exactly the point and purpose of using logarithmic scale, to pinpoint the **small** difference).

So basically if you want to have a more "proper" fitting, the fitting function itself need to be improved.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. What fitting function did you used in the first plot?

Comment: yours, I didn't use any other function. I just display it differently. Both plots have the same fitting function, the first plot has linear yscaling,, while the second plot has log yscaling.